How to move a destination on top of the back stack
I'm using Compose Navigation, my Android app has 4 screens, each screen has a bottom navigation bar to navigate to other screens:

screen A (the home screen, has 3 buttons to navigate to B, C and D)
screen B (has 3 buttons to navigate to A, C and D)
screen C (has 3 buttons to navigate to A, B and D)
screen D (has 3 buttons to navigate to A, B and C)

If, for example, my current back stack is A > B > C > D and I want to navigate to screen B, how can I move the screen B at the top of the back stack without removing other screens?
The back stack should become A > C > D > B. And when the user navigate to the screen A the back stack is cleared. When the user press the back button the current screen is popped out.
I thought that launchSingleTop = true would solve this, but it really just serves to ensure that there are no duplicate destinations near each other.
This is my current code on screen A to navigate to other screens:
composable<Route.ScreenA> {
    val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
    ScreenA(
        onNavigate = {
            val currentState = lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.currentState
            if (currentState.isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)) {
                navController.navigate(route = it.route) {
                    launchSingleTop = true
                }
            }
        },
        onCloseApp = {
            if (context is Activity) {
                context.finish()
            }
        }
    )
}

And this is my current code on screen B (same as screen C and D) to navigate to other screens:
composable<Route.ScreenB> {
    val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
    ScreenB(
        onNavigate = {
            val currentState = lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.currentState
            if (currentState.isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)) {
                when (it.route) {
                    Route.ScreenA -> {
                        navController.navigate(route = Route.ScreenA) {
                            launchSingleTop = true
                            
                            // to remove all screens from the back stack except screenA
                            popUpTo(Route.ScreenA) { inclusive = false }
                        }
                    }
                    else -> {
                        navController.navigate(route = it.route) {
                            launchSingleTop = true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        onNavigateBack = {
            val currentState = lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.currentState
            if (currentState.isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)) {
                navController.popBackStack()
            }
        }
    )
}

Thanks in advance.
